# How long is an app downloadable from the App Store?

Tags: ios-appstore

I'd like to know how many years an app is downloadable/distributed in App Store after a developer uploads it.

Answer (score 1):

An app is downloadable/available on the App Store as long as the app developer or the publishing company has an active developer license with Apple.

Comment: And also while it is compatible ith Apple supported version of iOS - for an example see 32 bit apps being removed

Comment: Additionally, developers can choose to remove apps.

Users with local backup of a removed application will still be able to re-install them on their device/computer, but those who don't have a copy of the app won't be able download / re-install them (even if they have paid for them).

For example, Electronic Arts has deleted full priced paid games when it has wanted to promote other similar titles (e.g. such as with SimCity). In practice, continued access to apps (including paid apps) is dependant entirely on Apple and publishers; even apps restored from local backup can be invalidated.